# Wildcard DNS setting in Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS Server not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, wildcard

We've got a windows server 2008 R2 DNS server that we are trying to setup a wildcard DNS entry in. So we want proxy.domain.com and *.proxy.domain.com to go to the same IP. Right now, it seems as if the windows server has registered the *actual* asterisk as the subdomain. So *.proxy.domain.com resolves to the right IP but something like login.proxy.domain.com doesn't.

This seems to be a problem specifically with 2008 because we were able to get this working on a 2003 server. Has anyone come across this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try using dnscmd

dnscmd servername /recordadd proxy.domain.com * A IPAddress

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;840687

Answer (score 1):

The DNS Console GUI just happens to present it as though it is a subdomain though in fact it is not.  If you look at the true data by doing a conventional zone transfer, for example, you will see that the wildcard RR is there.