# Can we put random entries on DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-dns, wildcards

Using microsoft DNS
All/most of our local hosts ( with in ) are in following domain

`*.company.org`
So a host name will look like `mymachine001.company.org`

Is it possible to set up wild card DNS entries of the form ?

`*.subd.company.com`

Note: The URL ends with `.com`, all other hosts so far ever set up in the DNS were of the format `*.company.org`

what i am trying to achieve is the following. A user with in internal network types a url `http://someprefix.subd.company.com` in browser and enters. Since there is a wild card entry in DNS, the user gets routed to host mapped to `*.subd.company.com` in the DNS

Note :  at the same time, `company.com` has a public DNS entry and that is mapped to a physical IP in some other network (data center)

Comment: It is possible, but probably not what you want - it would be helpful if you could explain a little further what you want to achieve?

Comment: You don't put "URL entries" in the DNS. URL is a Web concept, not a DNS one.

Comment: @ringbearer Wait, is the fact that your normal hosts are in .org and you're asking about .com pertinent the question or is that a typo?

Comment: That was not a typo - that was the intent

Comment: @ringbearer Cool, see my answer then ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - you will need to create a DNS zone on your DNS server(s). You can do one of two things:

```
Create a zone for the whole of `company.com` and then add *.subd
```

The advantage is that you will have complete local control over this domain, the potential disadvantage is that it create a full split DNS setup. Meaning that if a load of subdomains exist (E.g, mail.company.com, staff.company.com etc etc) you will need to recreate all these in your DNS Zone.

or

```
Create a zone JUST for `subd.company.com` and then a wildcard for the whole thing
```

The advantage here being that mail.company.com will still go through your normal forwarding routes meaning you don't have to mess. The disadvantage is that you need to be very aware of what you do and don't have zones for. Troubleshooting may be more difficult and it will get terribly messy if you want subd2.company.com and subd3.company.com in the future.

The best solution will really depend on what `company.com` is currently doing and what you want it do. You also need to very clear that running the zone locally means you now have two possible places where DNS entries are. You should ensure you clearly understand your forwarders and so on.

Comment: No, creating a zone is not necessary. A subdomain is sufficient.

Comment: @bortzmeyer Sorry if I've missed something, but how? His domain will be .org, and he needs a .com zone

Comment: Try to avoid a split zone scenario. Just try to add local subdomains for the specific things that you want to handle internally.

Comment: @jishi Split-DNS isn't automatically a bad thing, you just have to be aware of what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. Just setup an `A` or `MX` record in the form `*.subd.company.com`. Any more specific answer is dependant on your DNS Server.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. So, does that mean that we can treat DNS records just like `/etc/hosts` entries ?

Comment: @ringbearer answering this question would require knowledge about how you actually treat `/etc/hosts`. Of course, both mechanisms provide a mapping between names and IP addresses, DNS as a server-based approach and the `hosts` file as a local approach. For some hints on how to implement a wildcard entry with MS DNS see http://serverfault.com/q/215270